# Why these questions are not duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

There are these two questions:

[(Theoretical) Multivariable Calculus Textbooks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522)

[References for the multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43290)

I was wondering why no one has marked them as duplicate of each other. Or is there some fundamental difference between these two questions that I am missing?

**EDIT:** These questions have now been marked as duplicates.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Apparently, [someone did](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522#comment98908_44522), but it didn't follow through for some reason.

Comment: Because [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488783/uniqueness-of-solutions-of-ax-b-and-ya-b-in-a-semigroup) is not a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346595/prove-that-g-circ-is-a-group-if-a-circ-x-b-and-x-circ-a-b-have-uni). This happens when a forum is conrolled publically.